# R Convert Row Labels To Column

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

Using R I have been passed (from another programmer whose code I cannot touch) a matrix of numbers that have column and row names labelled. Something like this:

```
       Height    Width
Chair     25       26
Desk      18       48
```

I want to convert this into a data from the matrix above into a data frame that is in the following format:

```
            Height   Width
[1,] Chair     25      26 
[2,] Desk      18      48
```

Where the first column name is a (' '). I do not know the Row names in advance and I cannot change the original code. How would I convert this simply and efficiently using R?

In other words I simply want to place row names into the data set.

Comment: I realized I can't do this exactly. The answers below both work and will turn it into a data.frame...but by doing so it won't work like a matrix and so my other code which is needing a matrix will have to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i think this do what you want :

```
mat <- matrix(c(25, 18, 26, 48), nrow = 2, dimnames = list(c("Chair", "Desk"), c("Height", "Width")))

 df <- data.frame(row.names(mat), mat, row.names = NULL)

> df
 row.names.mat. Height Width
1          Chair     25    26
2           Desk     18    48
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it is not quite right, this puts output as you show but if it is in the form I need it will print out exactly as I show above such that instead of 1 for the row it will [1,] and instead of 2 it will be [2,] etc... Any ideas?

Comment: Then it's a matrix you want not a data frame. What's the problem with a data frame ? You can access to lines with `df[1,]` as well. And in a matrix all the data have the same type, then it will cast your intergers into strings. Definitly a data frame is better, i think.

Comment: Yes I just realized that it would have to be a matrix not a data.frame to do what I want. The reason is because I am taking matrix and passing them to the RJSONIO toJSON method. Passing a matrix into that method produces the desired json results passing in a dataframe produces a different type of json string that ultimately the jquery datatable code doesn't recognize. Therefore, it seems your answer is correct. I can't do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2):

```
M <- matrix(c(25,18,26,48), 2)
rownames(M) <- c("Chair", "Desk")
colnames(M) <- c("Height", "Width")

DF <- data.frame(furniture=rownames(M), M)
rownames(DF) <- NULL
#   furniture Height Width
# 1     Chair     25    26
# 2      Desk     18    48
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it is not quite right, this puts output as you show but if it is in the form I need it will print out exactly as I show above such that instead of 1 for the row it will be [1,] and instead of 2 it will be [2,] etc... Any ideas?

Comment: I realized that I can't do what I want because I really want a matrix of mixed types and you can't do that in R...that is what data.frames are for.